# React ocation.pathname typerror: Cannot call location.pathname in one file, but can in other file

Tags: reactjs, undefined, pathname

In one of my Components, I can easily call a "this.props.location.pathname". But when I try this in another component I get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

And I can't seem to find out what is different..

### WORKS:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class RedirectUser extends Component  {
    render () {
        return (
            <span className='redirecting'>
                {this.props.location.pathname === '/' || this.props.location.pathname === '/mgmt' || this.props.location.pathname === '/mgmt/' ?
                    <Redirect to='/mgmt/entrepreneurs' />
                : this.props.location.pathname === '/user' || this.props.location.pathname === '/user/' ? 
                    <Redirect to='/user/settings' />
                : this.props.location.pathname === '/dev' || this.props.location.pathname === '/dev/' ? 
                    <Redirect to='/dev/story' />
                : null
                }
            </span>
        );
    }
};
```

### DOESN'T WORK

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Icon from '../library/icons/Icon';
import '../App.css';
import { UserConsumer } from '../App.js';
import ProfilePicture from '../library/imgs/examples/profilepic.jpg';

export default class MainNavigation extends Component  {
    constructor (props) {
        super (props)
        this.state = {
            nav: this.props.location.pathname === '/mgmt' ? 
                    'management' 
                :this.props.location.pathname === '/social' ? 
                    'social' 
                :this.props.location.pathname === '/work' ?
                    'work'
                :this.props.location.pathname === '/dev' ?
                    'dev'
                : 'management',
            navFloat: false,
            greeting: '',
            mobileMenu: false
        }
        this.closeNavTab = this.closeNavTab.bind(this);
    }
...
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your navigation component is not a route component.
[Component that you use in your react-router configuration against a route]

I'm guessing RedirectUser component is one such component

e.g

```
<Route path='...' component={RedirectUser}/>
```

Only these components have access to this.props.location.

You will need to pass the prop to your navigation component or as @jens suggests use the withRouter HOC with MainNavigation

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
.... 
....
export default withRouter(MainNavigation)
```

Comment: I added  a `console.log(this.props.location.pathname)` to both componentWillMount  and componentDidMount yet it still gives me the error.

Comment: You could use the HOC withRouter on MainNavigation to give it roter props.

Comment: It still doesn't work, but I know why.
When I call a route like this:
`<Route path='/' component={Path} />`
I can access the location.pathname. But like this: 
`<Route path='/' render={() => <Path device={this.props.device} />} />` it doesn't work, yet it is the second way I need to pass props.

Comment: You could still use the withRouter HOC on Path component. You will have accees to the router properties history, match and location when you wrap it in the withRouter HOC

Comment: That'll do it! :) Thank you!